# sendAction is not working for component in ember js

Tags: ember.js

sendAction is not working for component. When using component inside view and sending action from component to view.

**confirm-dailog.js**

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions:{
       closeConfirmDialog:function(){
          this.sendAction('onCancel');
       }
   }

})
```

**confirm-dailog.hbs**

```
<div class="dialog" id="dialog">
   <div class="text">{{text}}</div>
   <div class="button"{{action 'closeConfirmDialog'}}>Cancel</div>
</div>
```

**modal.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.View.extend({
   layoutName: 'components/modal-box',
   actions:
   {
       closeDialog:function()
        {   
            console.log('called model closedialog')
        },
   }
})
```

**modal-box.hbs**

```
<div class="dialog" id="dialog">
    {{yield}}
    {{confirm-dialog onCancel="closeDialog" text="Would you like to close the modal"}}
</div>
```

when i am clicking on cancel button **closeConfirmDialog** action gets called and from there i am trying to send **closeDialog** action but its showing error *Nothing handled the action 'closeDialog'*

[here i have added screenshot of ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGtCm.png)

**Ember      : 1.8.1**

**Ember Data : 1.13.7**

**Handlebars : 1.3.0**

**jQuery     : 1.11.1**

Comment: Why are you using Ember.View instead of Ember.Component in modal.js?

Comment: @ykaragol Ember.Component is working. but i have some cases where view is only suitable.

Comment: Can you make it a twiddle? Actually we've never had a need for views in our 7 ongoing projects.

Comment: this.render(name, {
                into: 'application',
                outlet: 'modal',
                view:'common/modal'
            });    this is the case . i have used view

Comment: At documentation, the view parameter is defined as: "the view associated with the 'post' Route". You can give a template of a route if you want. Do not use Views because of this.

Comment: @ykaragol is it not possible to send action from component to view. ?

Comment: I've never used views. But there must be something that handle the action. (Maybe controllers?) But imo, try to use components. Try to change parameters of `render`.

Answer (score -1):

Views are removed from Ember 2.0 API. http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view

I would encourage you to replace `view` with `Component`.
Moreover for your requirement [ember-elsewhere addon](https://github.com/ef4/ember-elsewhere) or [ember-modal-dialog](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog) would be most suitable.